# Reset input on uncheck checkbox (ReactJS + Formik)

Tags: reactjs, formik

I made this component to create a field if a checkbox is checked, but how can I reset this field value if I write something and then uncheck?

```
const InputCheckbox = ({name, size}) => {
  const [checkAmount, setCheckAmount] = useState(false);

  return(
    <div>
    <label htmlFor={size}>
      <Field type="checkbox" name={name} value={size} onClick={()=> {checkAmount === false ? setCheckAmount(true) : setCheckAmount(false)}} />
      {size}
    </label>
    {checkAmount === false ? null : <div className="form-control-amount">
      <label htmlFor={`sizeamount.${size}`}>{size}</label>
      <Field className="form-control-amount" type="number" name={`sizeamount.${size}`} />
      </div>}
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, but `setCheckAmount(!checkAmount)` would be more concise. As well as `{checkAmount && <div ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Formik's `setFieldValue` function to reset the field when the checkbox is unchecked.

Your component:

```js
const InputCheckbox = ({name, size, setFieldValue }) => {
  const [checkAmount, setCheckAmount] = useState(false);

  return(
    <div>
    <label htmlFor={size}>
      <Field type="checkbox" name={name}  checked={checkAmount} value={size} onClick={()=> {checkAmount === false ? setCheckAmount(true) : setCheckAmount(false); setFieldValue(`sizeamount.${size}`, '')}} />
      {size}
    </label>
    {checkAmount === false ? null : <div className="form-control-amount">
      <label htmlFor={`sizeamount.${size}`}>{size}</label>
      <Field className="form-control-amount" type="number" name={`sizeamount.${size}`} />
      </div>}
    </div>
)
}
```

Usage:

```js
<Formik
    initialValues={{
        check: true
    }}
    onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        alert('Form has been submitted');
        actions.setSubmitting(false);
    }}
>
    {({setFieldValue}) => (
      <Form>
        <InputCheckbox name="check" size={10} setFieldValue ={setFieldValue} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

Reference: https://formik.org/docs/api/formik

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
<button 
        class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
        type="reset"
        onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  props.resetForm()
                         }}                       
>Eliminar filtros</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).